# HTML5 Video Loop Never Hits 100 Percent Duration

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to fire an event when video playback has reached 100%.

When the video is not looped, I get (currentTime/duration * 100 === 100) as true. 
When the video is on loop, I never get 100.

Any suggestions?

[JSFiddle Link Here](http://jsfiddle.net/asimgeker/xG22p/)

Here's the HTML.

```
<h3>Without Loop</h3>

<div>Current: <span id="console2"></span></div>
<div>Has hit 100%: <span id="hundredIsTrue2" class="red">No</span></div>
<video id="video2" autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

<h3>With Loop</h3>

<div>Current: <span id="console"></span></div>
<div>Has hit 100%: <span id="hundredIsTrue" class="red">No</span></div>
<video id="video" autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Here's the JavaScript.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    console = document.getElementById('console'),
    hundred = document.getElementById('hundredIsTrue'),
    video2 = document.getElementById('video2'),
    console2 = document.getElementById('console2'),
    hundred2 = document.getElementById('hundredIsTrue2');

    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {
        console.innerHTML = e.target.currentTime / e.target.duration * 100;

        if (e.target.currentTime / e.target.duration * 100 === 100) {
            hundred.className = 'green';
            hundred.innerHTML = 'Yes';
        }
    });

    video2.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {
        console2.innerHTML = e.target.currentTime / e.target.duration * 100;

        if (e.target.currentTime / e.target.duration * 100 === 100) {
            hundred2.className = 'green';
            hundred2.innerHTML = 'Yes';
        }
    });
```

Here's the CSS.

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeupdate` event does not actually run on every frame. It runs approximately every 250ms or 1/4 second. So it looks like what's happening here is that the last `timeupdate` event fires at less than 250ms before the end of the video and then the video ends and starts over back at the beginning before there's a chance for another `timeupdate` event to fire. So the next `timeupdate` event that fires will report `currentTime` at or close to zero.

So if you want to have your video automatically loop, there's a few things you can do to detect the end. One option is to look for a time that's sufficiently close, like maybe 0.5 second before the end. Another option is to wait for the `seeked` event, which should fire as the video ends and seeks back to zero, but that won't be helpful if you also allow the user to manually seek around the video.

A third option is to disable automatic looping and listen for the `ended` event. `ended` fires when the video gets to the end, but only if the `loop` property/attribute is not enabled. When you receive the event, you can fire your event, set `currentTime` back to 0 and call `.play()` again.

Comment: Interesting. The third option would work the best IMO. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The calculated value moves from the 90s back to 0 without hitting the exact value 100.
Would something like the below help? There is a possiblity of the value not hitting 99 either. Setting a smaller value like '95' might work for what you want to achieve.

```
if (e.target.currentTime / e.target.duration * 100 > 99) {
        hundred.className = 'green';
        hundred.innerHTML = 'Yes';
    }
```

Comment: Between 95 and 100, there would be multiple times that the if condition would return true. I thought about this.